# Manipulating meta tags with data from controller in different scope

Tags: angularjs, dom, service, controller, directive

I have an angularjs application where I need to update a few meta tags (for fb sharing) based on data that the controller gets from a service.

Right now I am doing something like this in my ItemController when the controller gets the data from the service:

```
angular.element('head').find('#metaFbImage').attr('content', $scope.item.imageUrl);
```

This is really BAD and I want to do this in a directive. But I cannot figure out a nice way to do it. So far I have two alternatives:

1) A directive on the head tag. When the ItemController gets the data from the service I want to call a function in the directive that changes the meta tags. How can a controller call a function from a different scope ( is outside ItemController)?

2) A service that is injected into ItemController, and the service changes the meta tags. This is a slightly better (and workable) solution. But is it OK to manupulate DOM elements in a service in cases like these?

EDIT: So I chose to refactor this into using $rootScope in the controller, and watching $rootScope in a directive on the head. I feel that this is somewhere between acceptable and bad practice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use this approach.

Create a Service (Factory) with parameters such as 
`

```
angular.module("myApp").factory("OGFactory", function(){  
    var OGFactory = {  
        title : "",  
        description : "",  
        ...  
    };  
    return OGFactory;
});
```

set your `ng-app` on the `<html>` element as `<html ng-app="your_app_name">` so that the `<head>` block can access items within your ng-app.

inject OGFactory into your Controller.  also inject it into your `$run` block and set it on `$rootScope` as `$rootScope.OGFactory = OGFactory`.

After your controller has done whatever it needs to do (if anything is async), set `OGFactory.title` and `OGFactory.description`.

In your `<head>` section, include meta tags such as: `<meta name="og:title" content="{{OGFactory.title}}">`

The controller will set the OGFactory properties and the rootScope will reflect them.

Note, however, that Facebook does not wait for Javascript to be done processing in order to fetch the page results, so your {{title}} will just look like (literally) 
"{{title}}" unless you use a service like prerender.io.  This method works great with prerender.